# Не понимаю почему не работает дискорд бот

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Соединил несколько кодов из интернета в один для своего дискорд бота, из всех функций (Табличка с информацией, игровой статус, сообщение при входе, радужная роль,  работает только радужная роль. Ошибок никаких не вылазит, не понимаю что нужно изменить.

```
import discord
from discord import utils
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import random
import os

token = 'token'
serverid = id

client = commands.Bot( command_prefix = '.')
client.remove_command( 'help' )
PREFIX = "."

# Табличка с информацией

@client.command()
async def info(ctx):
    print('Табличка с инфой работает')
    embed=discord.Embed(title="ПИ-БОТ", description="Бот для ПИ-18(9)", color=0x0080ff)

    embed.add_field(name="Cоздатель:", value="name", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Версия:", value="1", inline=True)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = 'url')
    embed.set_footer(text="Бот")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

# Игровой статус

@client.event
async def ready():
    print( 'Игровой статус работает' )
    await client.change_presence( status = discord.Status.online, activity = discord.Game( 'game'  ) )

#Сообщение о том, что Юзер зашёл на сервер + выдача роли
@client.event
async def on_member_join( member ):
    print('Приветственное сообщение работает')
    emb = discord.Embed( description = f"**{member.mention}** зашел на сервер, добро пожаловать!", color = 0x0c0c0c )
    role = discord.utils.get( member.guild.roles, id = id ) # Айди роли, которая будет выдаваться, когда человек зашёл на сервер

    await member.add_roles( role )
    channel = client.get_channel( id ) # Айди канала, куда будет писаться сообщение
    await channel.send( embed = emb ) 

# Радужная роль

client = discord.Client()
colours = [discord.Color.dark_orange(),discord.Color.orange(),discord.Color.dark_gold(),discord.Color.gold(),discord.Color.dark_magenta(),discord.Color.magenta(),discord.Color.red(),discord.Color.dark_red(),discord.Color.blue(),discord.Color.dark_blue(),discord.Color.teal(),discord.Color.dark_teal(),discord.Color.green(),discord.Color.dark_green(),discord.Color.purple(),discord.Color.dark_purple()]
rainbowrolename = "name"
delay = 5

@client.event
async def rainbowrole(role):
    for role in client.get_guild(serverid).roles:
        if str(role) == str(rainbowrolename):
            while not client.is_closed():
                try:
                    await role.edit(color=random.choice(colours))
                except Exception:
                    print("can't edit role, make sure the bot role is above the rainbow role and that is have the perms to edit roles")
                    pass
                await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print('role with the name "' + rainbowrolename +'" not found')
    print("creating the role...")
    try:
        await client.get_guild(serverid).create_role(reason="Created rainbow role", name=rainbowrolename)
        print("role created!")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        client.loop.create_task(rainbowrole(rainbowrolename))
    except Exception as e:
        print("couldn't create the role. Make sure the bot have the perms to edit roles")
        print(e)
        pass
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        client.loop.create_task(rainbowrole(rainbowrolename))  

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    client.loop.create_task(rainbowrole(rainbowrolename))
    print('Радужная роль работает')     

client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насчет статуса и роли - работает только роль из-за особенностей работы декоратора `@discord.Client.event` Этот декоратор заменяет в классе клиента метод определенного ивента тем, которая находится под декоратором. Вот и получается, что код статуса просто "исчезает". Необходимо объединить оба этих метода.

По остальным проблемам, хотелось бы больше информации, так как код выглядит вполне рабочим.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь Iterator.
Я убрал "client = discord.Client()", заменил у статуса @client.event на @client.command() и все функции заработали.